# Ruby on Rails Scope : wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, search, scope

I have a `User` model and I use scopes to search users + sort the results. For example, select users whose name start with "..." with ascending order. This scopes work fine:

```
scope :like, ->(like) { where("name like ?", "#{like}%")}
scope :order_by, ->(order_by) { order("#{order_by} ASC") }
```

But what if I'd want to sort users on a chosen field and also choose order type (ASC/DESC)? I tried something like this:

```
scope :like, ->(like, filter) { where("#{filter} like ?", "#{like}%")}
scope :order_by, ->(order_by) { order("#{order_by} #{order_type}") }
```

...but this error occured: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`.
However, all parameters in server log seem to be right:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "filter"=>["email"], "like"=>"ex", "order_by"=>"email",
 "order_type"=>"DESC", "commit"=>"  Search  "}
```

How can I make it work? Thanks for your support!

**PS: users_controller.rb:**

```
include Filterable
...
  def index
    @users = User.filter(params.slice(:filter, :like, :order_by)).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 40)
  end
```

**filterable.rb** is the module where all the filtering logic is:

```
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
        results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
```

Comment: @jumpingcode, I had to skip using `filterable.rb` in this specific case, because it was meant to process 1 param only. Instead I just used scopes in common way like this: `scope :starts_with, ->(filter, starts_with) { where("#{filter} LIKE ?", "#{starts_with}%")}`. For more information see Justin Weiss answer (the author of filterable) here: http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/02/17/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/#comment-1549762825 . Ping me if you need some more info.